# Did Helen not bother finding out what Anthony does for a living?

Tags: plot-explanation, enemy

In the movie Enemy, Helen doesn't seem to know what Anthony does for a living.

One day she gets information about a person Adam (who claims to look like Anthony). She goes to see him. She finds out that it is (might be) Anthony who seems to think he's Adam and is a teacher. But this is a real job. Adam is a teacher.

Anthony on the other hand is an actor who didn't get more than 3 films, that too cameos. He doesn't have a career.

All this while, how did Helen never bother to find out what her husband did for a living? They live in a nice apartment, sosmething's gotta pay for it. Given she was quite suspicious about Anthony, would she not want to know what he did for a living?

Comment: anthony is rich from what looks like inheritance .. so it's possible that he doesn't have any job. neither an actor, nor a teacher. may be his mom is paying his bills?

Comment: hmm .. and Helen sees him at school .. understands that he's got issues.. and that's why she asks "How was school?" .. this movie is just plain hard to get!